# Using Listeners&Loggers in build.xml

Tags: ant

I want to use Listeners&Loggers in my script build.xml
I have seen the suggested method, but it is on cmd -logger org.apache.tools.ant.listener.ProfileLogger
Also gone through groovy method, but is there any other way I can specify Listeners&Loggers in my script.

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with the command line suggested approach?  Without sharing the problem there, nobody can suggest a "better" way.

Comment: I undo, sure let me explain.
we are using IBM's RTC, in which everything is integrated.
So we need to run script on RSA, and not on cmd.

Answer (score 0):

RSA is built on Eclipse.  Both let you select an Ant builder for a project.  Which gives you all the Ant options including a command line.